# Exclude page number from text when extracting from a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, text-extraction

I want to exclude the page number of a PDF from the actual text using `pypdf` package

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("pdf-examples/kurdish-sample-2.pdf")
full_text = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    full_text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
print(full_text)
```

**Output:**

```
5 دوارۆژی ئەم منداڵه بکەنەوە کە چۆن و چی بەسەر دێت و دووچاری
```

The number **5** is the page number which should be excluded.

Comment: Look in the docs: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/post-processing-in-text-extraction.html#header-footer-removal

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pass` method if the count of iterations is 5, just like this:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("pdf-examples/kurdish-sample-2.pdf")
full_text = ""

def extract_pages(reader, text):
    i=1
    for page in reader.pages:
        if i == 5:
            pass
        else:
            text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
        i = i + 1
    return text
full_text = extract_pages(reader, full_text)
```

Here we use `i` as iterations counter and add it everytime the page is read we add the counter by one. So if `i` is 5, that means that we are on the fifth page, and we just dont do anything with it by writing `pass`.